# What should Super User Blog put as a general bio for Lifehacker?

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

Lifehacker is interested in [reposting some of our material](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/05/how-to-maximise-the-life-of-your-ssd/) on their site.  They've asked what bio should we add to the posts?  This is what I replied with but I wanted to get everyone's opinion/suggestions:

> [Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com) is the official blog of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) site: [Super User](http://superuser.com).  We write about everything computer related including product reviews, productivity processes, and interesting questions/answers found from the Super User site itself.

Comment: perhaps add more about what SU *itself* is really about...

Comment: any suggestions @studiohack?  I don't want to make it too lengthy

Comment: agreed @KronoS...something from the FAQ would work, like that like: ` Super User Blog is the official blog of the Stack Exchange site for computer enthusiasts and power users, Super User.`.  Something like that will help clarify the scope of SU more clearly...

Comment: I like it... the fact you mention, "interesting questions/answers found from the Super User site itself." is probably the most important part since it will draw more traffic to the site.

Answer (score 8):

Proposal:

---

> [Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com) is the official
>   blog of [Super User](http://superuser.com), a
>   website (part of the [Stack
>   Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network) focusing on Q&A
>   of computer hardware & software. The
>   blog covers everything computer
>   related including product reviews,
>   productivity processes, and
>   [interesting questions/answers](https://superuser.com/?tab=hot)
>   asked by the Super User community.

Comment: feel free to edit, remix, add/remove any extra link/content as desired

Comment: I'd suggest that before we make this official, we get Rebecca's input/approval, since this is potentially a big avenue of publicity for the blog and Super User in general.

Comment: That's probably a good idea, @nhinkle and @Sathya, regarding checking with Rebecca.

Comment: @Nhinkle I've already sent the email to lifehacker :(  but I'm sure that I can tell him to hold off or even change it.